# Decimal to binary/hex using arrays

Tags: c++, decimal, converters

I'm having trouble with the hexadecimal part of my c++ program. When I use the switch for hexadecimal nothing returns. also for some reason my binary conversion has a leading 0 I cant seem to get rid of.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
void binary(int, int);
void hex(int, int);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int numb, base;
cout << "Enter a decimel number : ";
cin >> numb;
cout << "Enter a base you want number switched to: ";
cin >> base;
switch (base){
case 2: binary(numb, base); break;
case 8: break;
case 16: hex(numb, base); break;
default: break;
    }
}
void binary(int numb, int base)
{
    int bin[32] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        bin[i] = numb%base;
        numb = numb / base;
        i++;
    } while (numb != 0);
    cout << "\n";

    while (i >= 0){
        cout << bin[i];
        i--;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
void hex(int numb, int base){
    int i;
    int hex[10] = { 0 };
    for (i=0; i > 10; i++){
        hex[i] = numb%base;
        numb = numb / base;
        for (i; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (hex[i] >= 10)
            {
                switch (hex[i]){
                case 10: cout << "A"; break;
                case 11: cout << "B"; break;
                case 12: cout << "C"; break;
                case 13: cout << "D"; break;
                case 14: cout << "E"; break;
                case 15: cout << "F"; break;
                default: break;
                }
            }
            cout << hex[i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with your spacebar = if not indent the code

Comment: This is my first time posting and it gave me an error saying all code must be indented by 4 spaces. maybe i misunderstood and it meant a minimum of 4

Comment: @LogicalGates Why not simply using the appropriate [standard I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex), instead of rolling your own?? _"minimum of 4 spaces"_ is correct, think twice!

Comment: @LogicalGates - Just indent the code - it makes it readable

Comment: it a beginners class and we are only to use what was taught in class

Comment: The termination condition is wrong in `for (i = 0; i >= 0; i++){`

Comment: @MattMcNabb i saw that previous to your response and changed it to for  (i; i > 10; i++). I intialized int i = 0; btw.

Comment: @LogicalGates then your loop will never execute as `i > 10` is initially false. The exit condition for this loop needs to be when you cannot extract any more digits from `numb`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb i thought the i > 10 is when the loop will exit not begin. If i begins at 0 it should exit when it gets to 11. hmm your right it should be when no more digits can be extracted from numb. should it look like this for (i=0; numb == 0; i++)??

Comment: @LOgicalGates the loop continues while the condition is **true** . See Radiodef's answer for more detail

Answer (score 0):

#### `binary`

The problem is after the first loop, `i` is one greater than the last index. Just for example, say you enter `1`: the `do...while` loop is entered, the digit `1` is put in array index `0`, then `i` is incremented to `1`.

Then, in the second loop, both indexes `1` and `0` are printed. You can solve this by decrementing `i` before entering this loop:

```
i--;
while (i >= 0){...}
```

You should be doing something like that anyway, because if you ended up using all `32` digits, you would try to access `bin[32]` and the program may crash or output gibberish.

#### `hex`

The first loop's condition is infinite:

```
for (i = 0; i >= 0; i++){...}
```

It should be the same as your condition in `binary`:

```
for (i = 0; numb != 0; i++){...}
```

But you are not done yet because I've noticed you also have a bug in your printing:

```
if (hex[i] >= 10)
{
    switch (hex[i])
    {
        case 10:
            cout << "A";
            break;
        ...
    }
}
cout << hex[i];
```

If `hex[i]` is greater than or equal to `10`, it gets printed twice, once as a hex letter and once as a decimal number. To solve this you could, for example, use `continue` instead of `break` in your switch (to skip the second print), or use `else`:

```
if (hex[i] >= 10)
{
    switch (hex[i])
    {
        case 10:
            cout << "A";
            break;
        ...
    }
}
else
{
    cout << hex[i];
}
```

You also need to make the same correction as in `binary`:

```
// decrementing i before entering the loop
//   vvv
for (i--; i >= 0; i--){...}
```

---

[Your revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27093501/5) is not correct, `hex` should not have a nested loop. It was fine [before](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27093501/4), just with the corrections I've pointed out.

Comment: hmm ok i made the binary correction i just decremented before the loop instead of changing to a for loop. but for my hex im having two problems. its printing out backwards and its leaving the last remainder out. 1405 decimal to binary should be 57D yet im getting 75

Comment: Make sure you are not using the code in [your revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27093501/5), which is not correct. With the corrections I've pointed out, your code [from before](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27093501/4) works correctly.

Comment: edit** 
I just set i>=0 now i am getting last digit.

               for (i=0; numb != 0; i++){
   hex[i] = numb%base;
   numb = numb / base;
   for (i; i >= 0; i--)
   {
    if (hex[i] > 9)


its print out backwards because of the second for loop because i is in decrements. how can i make it print the opposite way